# Record not getting saved in table with PLSQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a record in DELIVERY_DETAILS but the record in not getting saved in table.Running the query individually saves the record .
Compile sucessfully.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CreateShipmentLinesTest

IS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO WSH_DELIVERY_DETAILS("DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID","SALES_ORDER_NUMBER","SALES_ORDER_LINE_NUMBER","SOURCE_SHIPMENT_NUMBER","SOURCE_SHIPMENT_ID","ORGANIZATION_ID",
"SOURCE_LINE_TYPE","CREATED_BY","SOURCE_LINE_ID","SHIP_FROM_LOCATION_ID","REQUESTED_QUANTITY","REQUESTED_QUANTITY_UOM",
"CREATION_DATE","LAST_UPDATE_DATE","LAST_UPDATED_BY","OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER") values (007023,'AK_JAN02_2019','1','1.1.1',20001,207,'SALES_ORDER',1006,4602,207,250,'Ea','01-MAR-96 12.00.00.000000000 AM','06-FEB-17 01.10.16.000000000 AM'
,'FUSION',2);
COMMIT;

BEGIN
  CreateShipmentLinesTest;
END;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compiling is just for compiling stored procedure. This does not execute your Stored Procedure.

In order to execute stored procedure, you need to run your Procedure with:

```
exec CreateShipmentLinesTest;
```

or

```
BEGIN
  CreateShipmentLinesTest;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked..Just had one query-Placing BEGIN
  CreateShipmentLinesTest;
END; inside code doesn't work..Is there any way to execute procedure without running any external command?

Comment: There's no error .. it's just the records is not getting created..I tried the above mentioned way..Updated the question..Can you please check

Comment: man your procedure is fine. Just you need to execute the given command in a new empty sql sheet

Comment: Yeah I executed it but as your above comment:BEGIN
  CreateShipmentLinesTest;
END; did not work...but cool i'll proceed with exec..Thanks